# Понимание Magento Block и Block Type

Tags: cms

Я хочу понять значение :

```
<block type="page/html" name="root" output="toHtml" template="example/view.phtml">
```

Хотелось бы очень понять `type="page/html"` , как формируется тип в блоках и зачем?

Объясните пожалуйста 
`type="A/B"` 
Откуда берутся А и Б тут?

Answer (score 0):

На самом деле все просто в типах блоков: это алис для понимания какой класс следует использовать для этого блока лэйауту. В вашем примере `type="page/html"` означает при отрисовке этого блока использовать класс `Mage_Page_Block_Html` потому, что:

1. **page** - алиас для имени класса `Mage_Page_Block` модуля `Mage_Page` полученный и файла `config.xml` соответствующего модуля (`app/code/core/Mage/Page/etc/config.xml`):

   ```
   <blocks>
       <page>
           <class>Mage_Page_Block</class>
       </page>
   </blocks>
   ```
2. **html** - последняя часть имени класса

Для понимания: если вы захотите вывести блок `Mage_Page_Block_Html_Topmenu` в своем лэйауте то вам следует указать тип `page/html_topmenu`.

Подробней в коде изучить как разбирается тип блока и формируется конечный класс можно в `Mage_Core_Model_Config::getGroupedClassName()` где аргумент `$groupType` является вашим типом блока (`page/html`). Для лучшего понимания стоит изучить класс лэйаута: `Mage_Core_Model_Layout`

**Важно:** Разделение через символ `_` актуально для типа блока, но не для темплейта (!). В пути темплейта используется стандартный разделитесь - `/`. Путь темплейта вычисляется от текущего пакета и текущей темы. Посмотреть можно в настройках какая у вас используется - *System > Configuration > Design*:

[image: System > Configuration > Design]